# Tool to search in open/running windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, windows-search, productivity

Does anyone know a tool to search among all open applications/windows in windows?

I generally have a lot of open windows of various applications on my desktop.

Finding a particular window becomes painful.

I had earlier used a free tool for this which worked like launchy where you can search among all open windows/apps but can't remember its name.

If you know any such tool then please share it.

Comment: I'm sorry, questions asking for software recommendations are off-topic here because they tend to go out of date quickly. You might be able to get help at [softwarerecs.se] after going through their asking guidance. For more information about our scope, see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Found the tool I was looking for
http://www.switcheroo.io/

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10， you can use WIN+TAB to show all the opened windows.

You can select the window you want, and you can search for the windows as the picture shows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer..
I found the tool I was looking for. 
http://www.switcheroo.io/